# How to delete previous table transaction if next table transaction fails

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, transactions

I'm inserting some data to tables one by one. I've two tables `adjustment_header` and `adjustment_grid`.

First I'll insert data to `adjustment_header` table then I'll insert data to `adjustment_grid` table. If adjustment insertion fails, previously inserted data in `adjustment_header` table should be delete automatically.

Is there any query for this kind of problem?

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_header values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"','"+TextBox4.Text+"')",conn);
conn.Open();
sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
//adjustment grid row 1
if (itemno1.SelectedItem.Text != "please select")
{
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_grid values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','" + itemno1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + adj1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + store1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + qty1.Text + "','" + cost1.Text + "')", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
//adjustment grid row 2
if (itemno2.SelectedItem.Text != "please select")
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_grid values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + itemno2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + adj2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + store2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + qty2.Text + "','" + cost2.Text + "')", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
//adjustment grid row 3
if (itemno3.SelectedItem.Text != "please select")
{
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_grid values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + itemno3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + adj3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + store3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + qty3.Text + "','" + cost3.Text + "')", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

In this code first I'm inserting data into `adjustment_header` table then I'm inserting into `adjustment_grid` table 3 times, in 3 transactions in `adjustment_grid` table any of one fails previously inserted data should be delete automatically.

Comment: Everything aside, you should **ALWAYS** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: `Rollback` the entire transaction block. Which is also known as `Cascading rollback`

Comment: please tell me how to use rollback in asp.net c#....?

Comment: Maybe this give You some idea: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the entire block in a [`SqlTransaction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx), and don't open/close your connection for each statement:

```
conn.Open();
using(SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction("Adjustment"))
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_header values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"','"+TextBox4.Text+"')",conn, tran);
    sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //adjustment grid row 1
    if (itemno1.SelectedItem.Text != "please select")
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_grid values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','" + itemno1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + adj1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + store1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + qty1.Text + "','" + cost1.Text + "')", conn, tran);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //adjustment grid row 2
    if (itemno2.SelectedItem.Text != "please select")
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_grid values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + itemno2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + adj2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + store2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + qty2.Text + "','" + cost2.Text + "')", conn, tran);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //adjustment grid row 3
    if (itemno3.SelectedItem.Text != "please select")
    {
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustment_grid values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + itemno3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + adj3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + store3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + qty3.Text + "','" + cost3.Text + "')", conn, tran);
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    tran.Commit();
}
```

You should also use parameters instead of string concatenation, but that's a separate issue...

I would ALSO not reference your controls directly.  Put this type of logic in a separate class in a function that has parameters for the various options.  That way you can decouple it from the UI and reuse it later if necessary.